# How to get sscanf to start scanning after \r\n\r\n in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing an HTTP client/server in C and I want to read the content (not the http header) into a string. since the last thing in the header is a \r\n\r\n sequence I need to tell sccanf to skip everything up until \r\n\r\n, and then start scanning at the first string after \r\n\r\n . I never really understood complex printf and scanf format descriptors, and everytime I try to read documentation I get confused quickly. My best try was `sscanf(str, [^\r\n\r\n]%s, mystr);` but it is not working.

Comment: Try this once -> `sscanf(str, %*[\r\n\r\n]%s, mystr);`.

Comment: use strtok(str,"\r\n\r\n") for the first part, and strtok(NULL,"\r\n\r\n") for second part

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`/`sscanf()`. They are almost never appropriate, and most of the cases, there are much saner alternatives. For tokenizing, there is `strtok_r()`.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax of scanf is pretty much the same as that of printf. Therefore what you'd want to use is:

```
sscanf(str, "%s\r\n\r\n%s", dummystr, mystr);
```

Of course, you need to allocate dummystr and mystr to be large enough to avoid buffer overflows (strlen(str) will do for both).

Comment: `"\r\n\r\n"` with match 0 or more white-space.  Not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char const* testString = "abcd\r\n\r\nthe rest";
   char str[20] = {};
   sscanf(testString, "%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]", str);
   printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Output:

```
the rest
```

Explanation of the format string:

```
"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
 |<-   ->| Read and discard everything that is not a \n or \r

"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
          |<-->| Read and discard the first \r

"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
                |<-->| Read and discard the first \n

"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
                      |<-->| Read and discard the second \r

"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
                            |<-->| Read and discard the second \n

"%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]" 
                                  |<-->| Read and save all the characters until the next \n
```

Comment: Note: `%*[^\r\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%*[\r]%*[\n]%[^\n]"` will fail `"abc\r\r\n\r\nthe rest"`, but should pass it.

Comment: @chux, my understanding is that the sequence to expect is exactly `"\r\n\r\n"`, not any combination of  four tokens consisting of `'\r'` and `'\n'`. Is that not correct?

Comment: The string `"abc\r\r\n\r\nthe rest"` has an exact `"\r\n\r\n"` in it.  Agree OP is not clear on what _could_ exist in the string.

Comment: I mean <anything>"\r\n\r\n"<content>. The "\r\n\r\n" is that exact string, and the content is what I want

Comment: @glen4096 The challenge is that `<anything>` could be followed by `"\r\r\n\r\n"` which means that the first `'\r'` of paired `"\r\r"` should be ignored as its is really part of the `<anything>`.  The remaining 4 `char` match the pattern.  It is the re-start of the pattern, once code is partially matching it is the challenge.  Its all your call.

Comment: @chux, excellent point. That cannot be handled by my suggested solution.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. In the <anything>, directly before the "\r\n\r\n" there will be a file size, so just a number. Before that number there will be "\r\n" sequences, but no "\r\n\r\n" sequences". I hope this clarifies it, sorry about the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach with a state machine

```
const char *rnrn(const char *s) {
  const char *pat = "\r\n\r\n";
  int ch;
  int i = 0;
  while (i<4) {
    ch = *s++;
    if (ch == '\0') return NULL;
    if (ch == pat[i]) i++;
    else if (ch == pat[0]) i = 1;
    else i = 0;
  }
  // Success ....
  return s;
}
```